# navigateToURL AS3 does nothing on Google Chrome only in my computer

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome

I'm facing a strange behavior of flash Player, on my iMac, running OSX 10.9.2, and Chrome  33.0.1750.146 with Flash Player 12.0.0.70.

I use the following function, to open a page and post to it some jpg data. It worked bofore on my iMac. I can't remember when it stopped working. It is working well on Safari.

On other computers I have, including a Macbook, that runs same chrome and same flash player version, it is also working as expected. So, it sounds crazy.

```
private function SharePicture(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {

                var bit:BitmapData = new  BitmapData(cena.width, cena.height);
                var shiftOrigin:Matrix = new Matrix();

                shiftOrigin.translate(-cena.x,-cena.y);

                bit.draw(stage, shiftOrigin);

                var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(95);
                var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bit);

                var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
                var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("some-page.php");
                jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);

                //percentLoaded_txt.visible=true;
                //percentLoaded_txt.text = processando;

                jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
                jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;
                navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "");


        }
```

I already completely removed Google Chrome and reinstalled again, and no way, to make this code work.

You can try it by yourself, by accessing the following page:
http://www.scrapee.net/en/photo-wall-collage.htm - Just access it, and blick "Save Photo" button on the bottom.

Have anyone an ideal about what is causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

navigateToURL takes 2 parameters. The second one, in your case empty string, is the target, where this new window will be open. Possible values are: "_blank"(new window/tab), "_self" (same window/tab) and two others if you work with frames(not flash frames): "_top" and "_parent". For more info:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html

If you don't pass anything as argument, default behavior is _blank, but in your case, you're passing a string, an empty string, and this could be the problem ...

Comment: the problem was Pepper Flash Plugin. Disabled it and not it is working. Thanks.